# I am new to coding and I keep getting : if rentalCode == 'D' and averageDayMiles < 100: TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python

### 4) Find out totalMiles:

## Prompt --> totalMiles = int(odoEnd) - int(odoStart)

## Prompt --> averageDayMiles = totalMiles/daysRented

## totalMiles = ?

```
    totalMiles = 2222 - 1234

    averageDayMiles = input(totalMiles/daysRented)

    if rentalCode == 'D' and averageDayMiles < 100:

        mileCharge = 0

   if averageDayMiles > 100 and rentalCode == 'D':

       extraMiles = averageDayMiles - 100

       mileCharge = extraMiles * 0.25*daysRented

   elif rentalCode == 'W':

      weeksRented = rentalPeriod

      averageMiles = totalMiles/weeksRented

   if averageMiles > 900:

     mileCharge = weeksRented * 100.00

  else:

    mileCharge = 0
```

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to code the above so that I do not get the following error :TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

If anyone has suggestions or can lead me in the direction of a link or reading that will help me better understand I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that input in python 3 will always return a string, not an integer. Therefore when you write averageDayMiles > 100, you are comparing a word and a number. You need to write the following:

```
if int(averageDayMiles) > 100 and rentalCode == 'D':
```

int(averageDayMiles) converts your string, into an int.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much I am making something that seems so simple after the fact seem so hard.

Comment: why would it give me a error such as this: NameError: name 'averageMiles' is not defined    I have defined it earlier within my coding.

Comment: I couldn't be certain without seeing the relevant code, and where the error occured, but it could be an error to do with the scope. For example, if you defined 'averageMiles' inside a function, and then refer to 'averageMiles' outside that function, it would be 'undefined' since it doesn't exist outside the function.

Comment: Also, could you mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes, Tim your answer was correct ty for helping me out so much.